# Getting the values from the multiselect Group in jquery plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on multiselect group.  Here is the link i have populated some data in the multiselect group and the users can select their requirements in that. 
http://vignesh.gvignesh.org/chose/chose.php

Here once show selected button is clicked i am calling javascript function.

```
function chos()
  {
        var a = $(".chzn-select").chosen(); 
        alert(a);
  }
```

it is not showing the selected values in alert box.  Some [object][object] is displayed. 
i dont know how to get the selected values.  If my javascript function for getting the values is wrong kindly let me know the new function.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I am getting source from this website.
http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: The `[object][object]` shown is the `select` element. The way jQuery works and most plugins is that the element is returned. I don't think using `.chosen()` is the way to retrieve the selected items - that's the constructor for the plugin.

Comment: Okay let me try some other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `$("#chossen").val()`, which returns an array of `value`s that are currently selected.

To get the actual `option` elements that are selected, try `$("#chossen").find("option:selected");`, and then loop through those (obviously) - in case you want to get their `text`.

Comment: @VigneshGopalakrishnan No problem. The plugin does the right thing and also actually manipulates the original `<select>` element, which is why this code actually works.